# The intransitive use of preposition 'up'

Tags: prepositions

The preposition 'up' can be used intransitively:

> **a.** **Put your hand up** if you know the answer. (toward a higher position)
>
> The prepositional phrase 'up' here functions as complement. It's both syntactically and semantically obligatory.

However, consider these examples from OALD and Macmillan:

> 1. Our profits are quite large when you **add them up**.
> 2. She got angry and started **smashing things up**.
> 3. Did you **lock the house up** before you left?.
> 4. The straps are all **tangled up** together.
> 5. He spent the evening **wrapping up** the Christmas presents.

I'm curious about the use of 'up's here. Unlike the first example, these five 'up's are optional, contributing little extra meaning to the whole sentences.

I think we could just omit these 'up' with the meanings unchanged. However, the real question is not all verbs could be paired with an omissible 'up'. In other cases, 'up' is just part of an idiomatic phrasal verb, as in 'let up', 'own up', etc.

It seems to me that these 'up's could be only paired with certain group of verbs when used in such a way.

Is there a common semantic factor licensing this particular use of 'up'?

Comment: I think you are confusing *telic*, a category of *lexical aspect* or *Aktionsart*, with *perfective*, a category of *viewpoint aspect*. *Swap* and *smash* are both telic verbs, implying an ultimate change of state. See our tag-wiki for [aspect](http://ell.stackexchange.com/tags/aspect/info).

Comment: @StoneyB Oh, I think I did confuse them. The post you wrote doesn't address how lexical aspect and viewpoint aspect interact. (BTW, it's not a criticism) Could you point to me where my mind gets tangled? This somehow relates to one of my previous Q: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/94995

Comment: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/82365/use-of-up-in-back-up-to-mean-going-in-reverse/111950#111950

Comment: Your examples seem a little bit shaky. `consume them up` isn't natural. It would just be `consume them`. `clear up your mind` is probably better said as just `clear your mind`, `tangled up together` doesn't need `together`, it can just be said as `tangled up`. `wrapping up the Christmas presents.` also sounds awkward and unnatural, `wrapping the Christmas presents.` works better. You're kind of right, omitting 'up' wouldn't change the meaning, it would, however, make the sentence sound better in examples 1, 3 and 5, and in example 4, you could either remove 'up' or 'together'.

Comment: The interaction is complex. For instance, statives and activities are inherently imperfective, but in some contexts a simple past or an experiential perfect will recategorize even a stative as perfective. Many telics can be recategorized as activities with an imperfective construction like the progressive or simple present, or with multiple objects.

Comment: To be fair, using **up** her free time wouldn't really have it's meaning changed if you omitted *up*. Only the word **all** would change the meaning of the sentence here. `Using up all her free time` `Using up her free time` Also, you cannot really omit the **up** from `Put your hand up`, as saying `Put your hand.` to someone would greatly confuse them. `Put your hands up in the air` and `Put your hands in the air` may be a better example.

Comment: @StoneyB  I extremely like it when you ascribe aspect to situations and the utterances which describe them, not to verbs. Can I say perfective/imperfective overrides *lexical aspect*?

Comment: @StoneyB In addition, does 'up' help to establish an inchoative reading among the five examples above?

Comment: @KinzleB A) No: 'perfective' refers to whether the action lay completely during the period under discussion, not to its internal structure. B) There are no inchoatives in those examples. *Inchoative* marks the beginning of the action; 'up' emphasizes (mildly) the sense that the action was carried out thoroughly.

Comment: @StoneyB In your tag wiki, esp the part of *aspect shift*, you mention: Mary’s finishing the report right now — it is re-categorized as an accomplishment, because the progressive compels you to look at finish as a process with duration. Does it count as an instance of aspect coercion?

Comment: @KinzleB I use the term 're-categorize' in much the same way as many linguists use the term 'coerce'.

Comment: @StoneyB I just made that up on the fly, but it turns out to be jargon. That was what I intended it to mean 'override' which failed to express my idea in the first place. BTW, in your example, why is it re-categorized into an accomplishment instead of an activity? I find it hard to pair a continuous tense with something telic.

Comment: @KinzleB *Finish* is ordinarily telic (+TEL) but without duration (-DUR)--it refers only to the final change of state. With *is finishing* it is still telic--it still implies that it ends in final change of state, but it now has duration. (+TEL,+DUR) is an **accomplishment**; an activity is (-TEL,+DUR).

Comment: You are probably confusing *Prepositional phrases acting as adverbs implying direction* with *Particles to form Phrasal Verbs*.
In cases such as: *He put his hands up* "Up" here is an adverb with a semantic value of direction; *He made up a lie* "Up" here is a Particle (Sort of an adverb used to create phrasal verbs) which has nothing to do with "He made a lie in an upper direction". I can't go any further in the particle subject since I didn't get interested in learning it at all.

Comment: Personally, I find Phrasal Verbs the most unnecessary words in the English language. Besides sounding informal and being disctinct throughout different regions over the world, it can be easily confused with a simple verb with an adverb. For non-native speakers, it is quite annoying to learn millions of phrasal verbs which can have different meanings according to the region.

Answer (score 1):

*Up* can be added phrasally (adverbially) to a lot of verbs to mean "X completely" or "X totally."

> It seems to me that these 'up' could be paired with certain verbs when the activities these verbs represent are expected to be finished soon. In other cases, it could be part of an idiomatic phrasal verb.

It can also mean "towards a state of being ready to use/perform/exhibit", e.g. *suit up*, *gear up*, *dress up*.

So you have this exactly right.  Some phrasal verbs like @Michael Curry's example *make up*, or other ones like *work up*, *shut up*, *show up* have different meanings.

Of course it's possible for an *X up* verb to have both multiple phrasal meanings - e.g. *wrap up* can mean *wrap completely* or have the different meaning *to conclude a matter*.

Comment: When I taught phrasal verbs in ESL I always pointed out that this completive sense of intransitive _up_ can work the same as _down_ in certain cases -- _the house burned up (completely) / down (to the ground); drink it up (completely) / down (to the stomach)_. Completive _up_ is often used to emphasize a verb: _beat him_ vs _beat him up_.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're partially right, but there are other cases in which up is paired with a verb.

> The story he told was made up

Means that the story he told was fictional

> She was all made up, wearing heels with a beautiful dress

She had a full face of make up on, wearing heels...

> She was getting fed up

Means that she was getting annoyed/angry

None of these apply to your theory and are all of different uses.

Comment: Source updated. And I'm 100% sure it's "up", not "out" that Tony was uttering. I have the movie in my computer.

Comment: All right, just seems like a weird word to be used in that sentence, but as I said, whether it was *up* or *out*, either could be omitted and the meaning of the sentence would not change.

Comment: Could it be a dialect?

Comment: I'm with Michael on this. It sounds like a transcription error to me too, or possibly the character fumbling  his lines up.

Comment: It's another question within this bigger one. I just provided a bad example. I think other examples would fit better with what I'm asking here.

Comment: You need to clear the question up then.